# How to adjust the difference between the coordinate from openstreetMap and google map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, openstreetmap, opengis

I have downloaded the OSM from OpenstreeMap that came with all nodes from the map and their respective coordinates. Now I have to plot a node (latitude and longitude) on Google Map, but  all coordinates goes in different places than it should be.

To illustrate I got the node -12.92122,-38.34991 (lat,long) on google maps and openStreetMap as you can see on screenshots[image: OpenStreetMap].

[image: Google Maps]

My question is how can I adjust these values.. so I can plot the node on google maps at the same place of openStreetMap.

Comment: Roberto: you may want to direct this kind of questions to http://gis.stackexchange.com  't is like stackexchange's got a Q&A site for everything now ;-)  (not a bad thing).  I know that Google Earth uses  WGS-84 coordinates, expressed in decimal degrees, and I _think_ that OSM uses WSG-84 as well. For fun, I moved the point to `-12.92105,-38.34975` on Google so that it would point to the same spot on OSM, but that provided no insight as to the source of this mismatch.  Experts on GIS.stackexchange.com are more likely shed light on this.